# angularjs routing: get template with data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following routing config

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'contactListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/new', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/form.html',
        controller: 'contactAddCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

my home page('/') simply loads a number of contacts and its contactListCtrl is like

```
myApp.controller('contactListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("list")
            .then(function(response) {
              $scope.contact_list = response.data;  
            });
});
```

So when I load the home page on browser, it loads the template and then send another request ('/list') to server to get the contacts (json). so the browser sends **2 requests** to the server.

Is this normal in AngularJS development to send 2 requests simultaneously to get template along with data? Is there any work around to send only  1 request to get both template and data ?

If I need send 2 requests in this case and suppose I have to load 5 templates in home page then I have to send another 5 requests to bind data (from database) to each template ?

Comment: I think you have mentioned ng-controller also in your template

Comment: @sasikumar sorry not understand what u mean..

Comment: Have you mentioned ng-controller="contactListCtrl" in Template also? , because in Route configuration also contains controller name related to templateURL, that is why it's trying to load two times

Comment: @saikumar actually I have not specified ng-controller any where, where should I specify ng-controller ? and what value ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resolve in the route, that ill load the data and than load your template. You can check here for solution [http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx](http://Resolve%20with%20ngRoute)